# Effective difference between “gem install --bindir ~/path/to/folder” and “--user-install” in Ruby

Tags: installation, ruby, gem

I don't have a desire at the moment to learn Ruby, but I just want to know what the difference is between `gem install --bindir ~/path/` and `gem install --user-install` as long as each of the paths are in my `$PATH`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the [Ruby GEM command reference here](http://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/):

```
-n, -​-bindir DIR - Directory where binary files are located

-​-[no-]user-install - Install in user’s home directory instead of GEM_HOME.
```

Effectively, and operationally you—as an end user using Ruby—would not really notice a difference if the file paths are in your `$PATH`. But each command clearly deals with a different filesystem aspect of a Ruby GEM install.

#### -​-bindir

`-​-bindir` refers to the `bin`ary `dir`ectory. Many Ruby GEMS install Ruby script files as part of their core library function *but* also install a “binary” as part of their install process. Meaning, if you are a Ruby programmer you might want to install a Ruby GEM so you can have a usable reference to it’s core code within your own custom code. But a binary file that performs an equivalent or “helper” task is installed along side those Ruby GEM library files. From a filesystem management point of view, some users might want to install those binary files in a separate directory instead of the default Ruby GEMs directory.

#### -​-user-install

So while `-​-bindir` is an option to control where binary files associated with Ruby GEMs get installed, `-​-user-install` is a manual override for where *all* Ruby GEM files get installed; binaries, libraries and other stuff like that. By using `-​-user-install` you are instructing Ruby GEM to install GEMs in the `~/.gem` directory which is—of course—in your user’s home directory. Without the `-​-user-install` option, the Ruby GEM files would be installed to wherever the default `GEM_HOME` path is.

Changing the default file path with `--user-install` will not negatively affect anything about operation. The Ruby GEMs would just be installed in a `~/.gem` directory—which is in your home directory—and Ruby will know to check there as well as it’s own default path for updates.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to clarify that for me. Will using `--user-install` for a gem (like [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/) for instance) affect anything about operation, future updates, etc.? Or was Ruby written to operate the same way whether gems are in `GEM_HOME` or elsewhere?

Comment: I don't have a `~/.gemrc` file, even after installation. Were you implying that the installation would create it or is that another step I need to take manually?